# How to overlap lines using two different date filters and accurately display diff%

Tags: powerbi, dax

It seems powerBi doesn't have the functionality to compare data from different time periods and overlap the results into one single visual. However, I came across the following article which allowed me to **almost** accomplish my task : https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filtering-and-comparing-different-time-periods-with-power-bi/
After applying the method in the article **(except from the normalization factor)**, I dragged the following values into a table visual

- Date (of my sales table), Total_sales (measure),
  previous_sales(measure), %difference

There are currently two slicer filters (current and previous date range) applied on the table:

- 10/1/2018 to 10/2/2018 & 9/1/2018 to 9/2/2018

The table's output is as follows:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
|    date     | total_sales    | previous sales | %difference |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| sept 1 2018 |                |      10,000    | -100.00%    |
| sept 2 2018 |                |      15,000    | -100.00%    |
| oct 1 2018  |      20,000    |                | N/A         |
| oct 2 2018  |      30,000    |                | N/A         |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

My two issues are: how to efficiently set it up so that the %difference can accurately calculate and how can I graph the lines so they can overlap into my line visual.
When I try to graph it, it gives me a line for sept. 1-2 and a long empty space before oct. 1-2.

N.B: This whole exercise is inspired by the GA comparison date feature in their visuals.

**Note: Please advise if you require my measure calculations (they aren't any different from the article and so are the relationships and Date tables)**

Comment: If you have the date on your axis, then of course you'll have a gap in the graph as the `total_sales` and `previous_sales` correspond to different time periods. Are you wanting the `previous_sales` to show up at a different date? Is that date always one month behind?

Comment: the date periods compared are always the same (5 days compared to 5 days in the past) but it could be 2 months ago 3 weeks ago (there's no logic to that). ideally the lines should overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we line up the two date ranges by the maximum date selected in each respective slicer (so that Sep 2 aligns with Oct 2 in your example). Define a `previous_date` measure as follows.

```
previous_date =
VAR MaxDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Date'[Date] ) )
VAR MaxPrev =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Previous Date'[Previous Date] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Previous Date'[Previous Date] )
    )
VAR CurrDate = MAX ( 'Sales'[Date] )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( CurrDate ), BLANK (), CurrDate - ( MaxDate - MaxPrev ) )
```

That is, we offset the "current date" we are calculating the value for by the difference of the last date in each slicer range.

At this point, your `previous_sales` can simply be

```
previous_sales = 
VAR PrevDate = [previous_date]
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales]), Sales[Date] = PrevDate)
```

The result should look something like this:

[image: Line Chart]

Comment: this seems to work because your previous_date you selected in your filter happens to fall in the same period of the current . but the previous date should never be in the same period (e.g. comparing the first friday to sunday of oct 2018 to the first friday to sunday of aug 2018).

Comment: No. It doesn't care if they overlap. What I'm doing is shifting the chart by the difference of the last date selected on the separate slicers. In my example, it's shifted by 2 months (12/31 - 10/31). I only left more range visible so it was more obvious what's happening. You can easily set the min `Date` selected so that there is no time period overlap.

Comment: realistically the user will never compare dates that overlap. so what if you try putting Oct 1-30 2018 as previous_date and Dec1-31 as current_date. thats what i mean. and see if there's a way to overlap them.

Comment: If I selected those parameters, the graph would just show the last month of what's already in the screenshot, the same exact values just focused on the narrower time period of December. Draw a box around the last right 1/12 of the chart and expand that.

Comment: The only place it doesn't overlape is the first two months where there is no data available to calculate `previous_sales`. You can see the Mar - May black line is identical to the Jan - Mar green line.

Comment: If my slicers are as follows: current: 11/1/2018 to 11/3/2018 previous: 10/1/2018 to 10/3/2018 and add a table with the following values: Sales[Date], Sales[Sales], previous_sales I get to see only my current dates in the date column, currents sales is fine but previous sales is the same for all three dates and its Oct 3rd 2018 only.